# How to get both predicted value and error metric in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have two separate python functions where one returns the predicted values of a dataset using `cross_val_predict` and the other returns multiple error metric values using `cross_validate`. Shown below is the method used to get the metric values ( I have implemented a similar method to get the predictions).

```
def metric_val(folds):
.
.
.
scoring = {'r_score': 'r2',
           'abs_error': 'neg_mean_absolute_error',
           'squared_error': 'neg_mean_squared_error'}

scores = cross_validate(best_svr, X, y, scoring=scoring, cv=folds, return_train_score=True)

print("****\nR2 :", "", scores['test_r_score'].mean(),
      "| MAE :", scores['test_abs_error'].mean(),
      )
return prediction
```

I don't want to use both functions at the same time as it's computationally expensive. Is there a single method or an alternative way to get both the predictions and the metrics?

Comment: Show how you defined `folds` and `scoring` and we can make a simple function to do that.

Comment: I have edited to include more details. Thanks

Comment: What is `folds`?

Comment: `folds` refer to the number of folds required for `k-fold cross validation`. For example, it can be `10` for `10-fold cross validation`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to rig a scorer so that it returns predictions, although it's a bit of a hack.  Here's how to do it:

The `cross_validate()` function can take custom scoring functions.  A scoring function has to return a number, but you can do whatever you want inside the function.  Since you have the `clf` and all the test data, just save the output of `clf.predict()` and then return a dummy value to keep the scorer happy.  See sklearn docs on [Implementing your own scoring object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object) for more.

Like this:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, cross_validate, cross_val_predict

# example data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target 
clf = svm.SVC(probability=True, random_state=0)
```

Define custom `get_preds()` function, sneak it in as a `scorer`:

```
def get_preds(clf, X, y): # y is required for a scorer but we won't use it
    with open("pred.csv", "ab+") as f: # append each fold to file
        np.savetxt(f, clf.predict(X))
    return 0

scoring = {'preds': get_preds,
           'accuracy': 'accuracy',
           'recall': 'recall_macro'} # add desired scorers here

k = 5
cross_validate(clf, X, y, 
               scoring=scoring, 
               return_train_score=True,
               cv = k)
```

Load `get_preds()` back in, reshape to match fold sets, and average across folds:

```
preds = np.loadtxt("pred.csv").reshape(k, len(X))
my_preds = np.mean(my_preds, axis=0).round()
```

Compare against `cross_val_predict()` predictions:

```
cv_preds = cross_val_predict(clf, X, y, cv=k)

np.equal(my_preds, cv_preds).sum() # 487 out of 500
```

We see almost perfect agreement here between the makeshift `get_preds()` approach and `cross_val_predict()`.  The small divergence may be due to my averaging approach being different from `cross_val_predict`'s (I just rounded to the nearest integer class, not very sophisticated), or it may have something to do with this slightly cryptic note in the [`sklearn` cross-validation docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#obtaining-predictions-by-cross-validation):

> Note that the result of this computation may be slightly different from those obtained using cross_val_score as the elements are grouped in different ways.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  `cross_validate()` *is* k-fold validation, it just has a default of `cv=3` (where `cv` is the kwarg for `k`).  But you can pass in any value `k` for the `cv` argument, it works just fine.  (I just checked on `cv=5` for this example data.)

Comment: I got that part. So does `clf.predict(X)` provide the same result as `cross_val_predict`? I want to get the predicted values as well but when I apply 10-fold cross validation and try to print out the values, it gives a large number of values unlike in `cross_val_predict`.

Comment: See updates - I had a bug or two, but my solution looks basically in line with `cross_val_predict` now.  Does that work for you too?

Comment: It returns more values than the dataset itself, giving this error `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3510 into shape (10,117)`.

Comment: Can you confirm my solution works on the example data I provided? It's a little hard to know what's going on with your data if you can't provide a [mcve].  Start by confirming that your question is answered in the general case with this solution, then let's see if we can figure out where your data and/or code has some kind of edge case that's messing things up.

Comment: I tried the code with the sample data provided but it still gives a value error, `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3000 into shape (5,150)`.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you ran the function a few times and it kept appending to the file?  3000 is 150*5 repeated 4 times...

Comment: No, I actually deleted the file before running it again.

Comment: I'm not sure how to debug your issue, I'm sorry.  I've checked a few times on my local install, I can't replicate the `size 3000` issue.  I did change the name of the file I was saving to (`"preds.csv"` to `"pred.csv"`), any chance you're still calling the file name from my earlier post version?  I still think best would be to generate a MCVE for yourself and provide expected output.  (Might be better as a separate question?)

Answer (score 1):

There is no predefined function which will calculate both prediction and performance metrics in sklearn.
But you can retrieve all performance metrics using [sklearn.metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics).